# Getting licenseReportCounter() exception , while starting the Jasper report

Tags: java, jasperserver, weblogic11g

I am getting a licenseReportCounter() exception when starting a Jasper report.

Jasper's License was valid and not expired.

**Exception**:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'heartbeatTrigger' defined in
> ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-logging.xml]:
> Cannot resolve reference to bean 'heartbeatJob' while setting bean
> property 'jobDetail'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'heartbeatJob' defined in ServletContext
> resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-logging.xml]: Cannot resolve
> reference to bean 'heartbeatBean' while setting bean property
> 'targetObject'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'heartbeatBean' defined in ServletContext
> resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-logging.xml]: Cannot resolve
> reference to bean 'heartbeatProContributor' while setting bean
> property 'contributor'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'heartbeatProContributor' defined in
> ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-logging-pro.xml]:
> Cannot resolve reference to bean 'licenseReportCounter' while setting
> bean property 'licenseReportCounter'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'licenseReportCounter' defined in class path
> resource
> [com/jaspersoft/ji/license/ApplicationContextLicenseConfiguration.class]:
> Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
> Factory method [public com.jaspersoft.ji.license.LicenseReportCounter
> com.jaspersoft.ji.license.ApplicationContextLicenseConfiguration.licenseReportCounter()]
> threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException:
> For input string: "" at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328

Jasper was running on a WebLogic server. I tried restarting the WebLogic server by stopping all the backend processes. But it did not work. I am not able to retrieve the reports via the Front end.

Answer (score 0):

We resolved this issue by deleting the ".jslic" and ".jseval*" which are available in our user home folder and then start the server again. It re-created these files after we started the server and the reports can able to retrieve from front end.

RCA: This problem occurred due to the corruption in auxiliary license files